# Dual monitor display settings reset when unplugging and replugging hdmi cable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, monitor, reset

So I am using the Nouveau driver because I was having problems with the Nvidia proprietary drivers. The thing is though, with the Nouveau driver, when I unplug my laptop from the HDTV that I use as a second monitor and plug it back in again, I get the default display settings, i.e. mirrored displays, with the lower resolution of my laptop screen being used instead of extended displays with my HDTV's resolution being used. I do not know what to do because I have saved the settings multi-time, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

It all works fine until I unplug the cable... when I plug it back in, I need to do everything over again...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Sometimes it helps if you turn the devices off before unplugging the cables. Sometimes changing the order you turn the devices off effects things. On one kernel version I had to turn the TV on before resuming and the next version I had to resume the laptop before turning on the tv *shrugs*. Oh yeah I forgot to mention since 2014 I've never used the Nvidia GPU, only the built in Intel GPU which has always been fast enough. Soon I might turn it on to play games under vulcan in 2017 or 2018 I guess. It is used for gaming under Windows but that's different.

Comment: Yeah this has been my experience too. Now I only use the laptop uplugged on Ubuntu if really need it, otherwise, I  boot up WIndows when unplugged.